# Scalable FCM notification model whilst app enters background

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have vehicle positions for over 10,000 vehicles currently coming into a Firebase Realtime database. Each vehicle is updated every 5 seconds on average.

I have been tasked with setting up a notification system with an app that allows these vehicles to be tracked.

If a user loads the app and begins tracking a vehicle by tapping on it, and then the app goes into the background, they should receive notifications every time the vehicle moves.

**My Proposal**

When a user begins tracking a vehicle, have them subscribe to a FCM topic with the topic name being the vehicle registration.

When our vehicle parsing script processes an update for a vehicle, if it has moved from its last location, send a notification to the topic.

When the user stops tracking the vehicle, unsubscribe from the topic.

Is this the best way of managing notifications for a Firebase setup?

Comment: I gave a quick answer on whether it is feasible. Whether it is "the best" is a highly subjective question, which makes it a bad fit for Stack Overflow. Just try it, and if you run into trouble report back with that concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topics are optimized for having a reasonable small number of topics with a reasonably large number of subscribers. While your use-case seems a bit different, having a topic per vehicle should technically work fine.

Comment: Many thanks Frank. Appreciate the subjective nature of the question. Is there a better platform/forum you know of for asking beginner Firebase questions/best practices?